# Как решить проблему добавления инпутов?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ребят, помогите исправить!

Есть форма с инпутами.
При нажатии на кнопку "добавить дополнительный номер" добавляется новая строка с телефоном и фио (это работает).

При нажатии на кнопку "добавить отдел. филиал" добавляет новый блок.

Проблема:

1. Если нажать на кнопку "добавить дополнительный номер", то добавлется 3-я строчка, и если затем нажать на кнопку "добавить отдел. филиал", то добавляется блок с 3-я строчками.
   Как сделать, чтобы всегда добавлялся блок с 2-я строчками?
2. При нажатии на кнопку "добавить дополнительный номер" в любом блоке она добавляется во все.
   http://jsfiddle.net/unior27/k8ck2ega/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема 1

Логично, что при нажатии на кнопку у Вас копируется каждый раз блок `#otdel`, именно в таком виде, в котором он на данный момент находится. Если в нем три `#number_block`, то он и скопирует три. Поэтому этот вопрос надо решать на уровне логики приложения. Нужен исходный вариант, тогда и храните исходный вариант.

```
    var otdel =  $("#otdel" ).clone();

    $('button.b2').click(function(){
        otdel.clone().appendTo( ".goodbye2" );
        return false;
    });
```

Проблема 2

Вы берете `#number_block` и копируете его во все блоки, которые содержат класс `.goodbye3` кодом `appendTo( ".goodbye3" )`. Логично, что это поведение добавит код во все отделы. Если нужно добавить в один отдел, то и добавляйте в текущий.

```
$('button.b1').click(function(event){
        $("#number_block" ).clone().insertBefore( this );
        return false;
});
```

Проблема 3

Не забывайте, что вы копируете объекты без событий, поэтому надо еще к ним привязать события или воспользоваться функцией JQuery, которая копирует объекты вместе с событиями (к сожалению, я уже забыл, как это делать правильно).

Проблема 4

Вы должны учесть, что у Вас там начинают повторяться атрибуты `id`, что по правилам HTML не допустимо, и атрибуты `name`, и когда все это дело будет отправлено из формы на сервер, может получится не очень весело.

P.S. Решение первых двух: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmhsxdf9/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, что подробно все расписали, только есть одна проблема:
когда создал новый "отдел/филиал",то в нем не работает кнопка "добавить дополнительный номер".  
Можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Это как раз из-за проблемы 3.

Посмотрел в документацию, надо привязать события и потом клонировать через clone(true): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmhsxdf9/2/)